# saveInstanceState is always null when using Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I am using Android Navigation component in my application while navigating back and forward from one fragment to another I realized that in the method `onViewCreated` saveInstanseState is always null, as I am loading data each time fragment is created I would like to have a check like

```
if(saveInstanseState == null) {
    presenter.loadData(...)
}
```

Comment: Is fragments `onDestroy` called? Or only view is destroyed (`onDestroyView`) and recreated?

Comment: Do you know how I can avoid onDestroy call? Some special flag in navigator?

Comment: I don't want my fragments to be rwcreated